# RowExpander With Dynamic Content

Tags: gwt, row, expand, gxt

I want to create a grid with a RowExpander. The problem I am facing is that each row has different information to be displayed in the expanded area. For example, each row represents a subject and the expanded area displays the grades related to this subject (exam1, exam2, etc.) as follows:

+math
  exam1      Excellent

exam2      Very Good

The problem is that i can't predict the number of grades (exams) each subject has, so a fixed template will not work in this case.

What is the best way to deal with such a case?

Note: if there is anything unclear in the question please ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have several options.

There is the Extended RowExpander that allows complexs widgets : [GXT Widget expander](http://github.com/kevinjqiu/gxt-widget-expander)

Or you could use and XTemplate with a nested TPL to iterate over the exams as per :

(I know that thread is for ext-js but the same principles apply to GXT XTemplates)
[Advanced XTemplate features](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?8025-XTemplate-New-Features-%28was-SuperTemplate-Feature-Request%29)